# Populate dropdown from sql table fields

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, servlets, drop-down-menu

How can I populate a dropdownlist in a .jsp page, retrieving fields names of a specific table from a mysql database?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you event try to use google ?

Comment: I tried but google google omniscience didn't help me
Thanks for your very useful suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider you have a class called DBConnection where you can connect to your DB.
Create a class called ListObject.java as-

```
package mypackage;
public class ListObject {
    public List<MyObject> getList() {
        Statement st = new DBConnection().getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from myTable");
        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            list.add(new MyObject(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Now on the jsp, use following-

```
<%@page import="mypackage.ListObject"%>
<select>
<%
    Iterator it = new ListObject().getList();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        out.write("<option value=\""+ object.getFieldA();+ "\">"+ object.getFieldB() +"\">");
    }
%>
</select>
```